# joomla plugin internal script code error

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

IN my joomla plugin I want to add internal script for animate css.but my code give error.

my code

```
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#canimation').addClass('animated "'. $this->_animation_c1.'"');  
    })  
');
```

Comment: Are you a user or a developer? What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

THere is an error due to quotes.Below code will work -

```
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $("#canimation").addClass("animated '. $this->_animation_c1.'");  
    })  
');
```

Answer (score 0):

A ; seems To be missing:

```
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#canimation').addClass('animated "'. $this->_animation_c1.'"');  
    });
');
```

And you are constructing your String wrong.
The Apostrophe in Front of #canimation will end the First string.

Try to build the String in a var at first and Output this var To See if it is the right one.

```
$jsString = "*your js code*";
echo "<pre>" . print_r($jsString, true) . "</pre>";
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($jsString);
```